# Tratar caracteres especiais

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

Estou tratando o retorno do CURL com SED, mas como a informação que recebo mas vezes tem o caracter / causa um erro na sintax do SED.

```
TOKEN=$(curl --silent $URL | awk -F '"' '/content/ {print $2}')
echo $TOKEN
```

**2CTVaTm46Uoregv0VcU2QPd15B3G/OpNgX7IAvL9cNs=**

```
sed -e "s/@TOKEN/$TOKEN/" $JSON_FILE > /tmp/$NAME.json
```

**sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to `s'**

Como posso especificar para o SED que quando houver / na variavel de substituição ele não deve interpretar como comando?

Comment: Utilize outro caractere, por exemplo `;` ao invés da barra. Ex: `sed -e "s;@TOKEN;$TOKEN;"`

Comment: Não sabia que eu podia usar outro caracter como separador, dessa forma resolveu pois no retorno não tem ;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No sed, passe o "barra invertida" antes da barra normal.

Ex: `sed '/channelType/,/\/channelType/!d' file.log`

No comando acima estou pegando um trecho do log que vai de "`channelType`" até "`/channelType"`.